# Mysql Table crashed. Should I repair daily?

Tags: mysql, crash

Out of blue moon, all of sudden, 1 of my database is crashed. This is not the first time, last time I use the "repair table" command and was lucky able to fix it. But it happens again, same table, same error, same solution.

```
Error:
1194: Table 'users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Do I need to repair my tables every day/week/month? Is there a permanent solution for "table-crashing" problem? Its really scary!!! Please help

Comment: Given that this has now happened multiple times to you I'm sure the thought has already crossed your mind, but how often do you back up? Even on relatively unimportant websites we do it hourly using cron/mysqldump/rsnapshot (which gives us a simple form of versioning). This tends to reduce the stomach-turning fear reaction on stuff like this.

Comment: Crashes can be caused by a number of things. server rebooting memory problems etc. To say its crashed is not enough information. lots more is required. and tracing them is as much an art as science. first of all enable logging. the answer may be in that

Comment: Please don't put urgent on your questions. We tend to ignore those.

Comment: My bad for putting the "urgent", but its very important to me. I cant sleep soundly because of this. I do the backup, everyday. Do I need to "repair tables" after backup??

Comment: Yes, my server is Windows Server 2003. Using IIS 6 and PHP as the server side script. The application is in flash.

Comment: I have never heard of something like this before. Maybe backup everything and reinstall MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't happen normally, if your tables are crashing it means something is wrong with your system.  Likely a bad disk or bad DRAM (or one of lots of unlikely things, like bad pci->sata bridge, etc...).  If you have another system around, try migrating to that system and see if your errors continue.

You do have another equivalent system around, right?  In case the primary DB crashes hard, and you need to restore a backup ASAP?

I suppose it could also be a bug in mysql, make sure the version you are using doesn't have known bugs.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this problem, let alone just about any other problem, start looking in your logs. If you MySQL server runs on Windows, there are event logs for application and system, and I would look at those. If your MySQL server runs on Linux, logs are usually found under /var/log, and you usually have to be root to view them. A good way to view on linux is
tail  (where  is replaced by the real name of the file).

As you have been advised in another answer, you might have disk issues. Run a hardware diagnostic on the disks.

Whatever you decide to do, please do not depend on repairing a table; because you soon might not be able to. Using an Informix SE database, I had to rebuild a table, and there was nothing apparently wrong with the data in the table. It was a nightmare, and took the better part of a weekend. I could not export the database, on which our test and development systems depend.